# Is here no slurmrestd version that matches slurm 2023?

Tags: slurm

recently I installed slurm 2023, want to use rest api, but I can not find a suitable slurmrestd version. I tried following ways, but it raised such errors.how to resove it. hope to your help:)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHmlo.png)

Comment: What repo are you using? or did you download an compile from source ?